# Why is my JavaFX 17 Application not building with Gluon ? Logged as JNI / Reflection problem

Tags: maven, javafx, java-native-interface, gluon, gluonfx

I am following the documentation given by Gluon : [here](https://docs.gluonhq.com/).

To try to make it simple I'll try to go straight to the point giving the milestones I got through, and where I'm stuck.

**--------- ENVIRONNEMENT :**
**OS :** Windows 10 x64
**IDE :** Eclipse, Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)
**JAVA :** jdk17.0.1
**JAVAFX :** javafx-sdk-17.0.1
**GraalVM :** graalvm-svm-java17-windows-gluon-22.0.0.2-Final
**Gluon plugin for Eclipse :** 2.8.2
**Visual Studio :** 1.63.2 (with all required extensions as described in document)
**Wix :** 3.11.2.24516

**--------- CONFIGURATION**
**Maven :** apache-maven-3.8.4
**Pom :** Here is an screenshot of the first part of my POM which can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-2DTnyrb1SarmFc1iCmEtRKzXkBvR4r0/view?usp=sharing).
[image]
**Environment Variables :** JAVA_HOME + GRAALVM_HOME + MAVEN_HOME
[image]

**--------- DONE :**
JavaFX(v17) Application :

- Running perfectly with direct RUN using regular JVM.
- Running perfectly with javafx:compile as proposed in Gluon's documentation
  [image]

**--------- PROBLEM :**
Impossible to get the Gluon goal "mvn gluonfx:build" or "gluonfx:build" to complete! Here is what I do :

1. As instructed to do [here](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_create_run_a_native_image_of_the_application_3) : "If you are running on Windows, you need to run all the GluonFX goals from a x64 terminal.", I open a "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022"
2. Navigated to my project folder where the POM is.
3. Runned the instruction `mvn gluonfx:build`. I also tried to follow the instruction suggesting to "open the Run Configurations…​ window and update the Goal to gluonfx:build and click Run". Both leads to a FAIL ! At the end of this post is the terminal report showing :

- I do run with the option mentioned --allow-incomplete-classpath.
- I do find the reported 'missing' cached_scope_id in the file jniconfig-x86_64-windows.json which is exactly on the mentioned path. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-GgNZJ6bqQto18S09PBylE-6-_7nAEtQ/view?usp=sharing) is the file if needed.
  [image]

I am trying since days to turn around everything, and searched the net for some clues... But no luck until now :-(... Can anyone help me sort this out please ?

PS. I do use an external DLL (yes, Windows only, but hey : we are trying here to make a NATIVE build, thus, in Windows ;-), should be ok); This DLL is JNI attached. I tried to play around with this as well... No luck.

**--------- TERMINAL REPORT :**
(Full log as mentioned, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-IXXyiIEouEtKCfQAqyNC29iFKDYzcx4/view?usp=sharing))

```
D:\_DEV\_Eclipse_IDE\_Workspaces\PRIVATE\GluonMobile_PlaylistProfiler>mvn gluonfx:build
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --< com.plpr.application:gluon-mobile---single-view-project--allow-incomplete-classpath >--
[INFO] Building Gluon Mobile - Single View Project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.8:build (default-cli) @ gluon-mobile---single-view-project--allow-incomplete-classpath ---
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --< com.plpr.application:gluon-mobile---single-view-project--allow-incomplete-classpath >--
[INFO] Building Gluon Mobile - Single View Project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.8:compile (default-cli) > process-classes @ gluon-mobile---single-view-project--allow-incomplete-classpath >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ gluon-mobile---single-view-project--allow-incomplete-classpath ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ gluon-mobile---single-view-project--allow-incomplete-classpath ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.8:compile (default-cli) < process-classes @ gluon-mobile---single-view-project--allow-incomplete-classpath <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.8:compile (default-cli) @ gluon-mobile---single-view-project--allow-incomplete-classpath ---
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:25 CET 2022][INFO] ==================== COMPILE TASK ====================
             _______  ___      __   __  _______  __    _
            |       ||   |    |  | |  ||       ||  |  | |
            |    ___||   |    |  | |  ||   _   ||   |_| |
            |   | __ |   |    |  |_|  ||  | |  ||       |
            |   ||  ||   |___ |       ||  |_|  ||  _    |
            |   |_| ||       ||       ||       || | |   |
            |_______||_______||_______||_______||_|  |__|

    Access to the latest docs, tips and tricks and more info on
    how to get support? Register your usage of Gluon Substrate now at

    https://gluonhq.com/activate



[lun. févr. 07 15:17:26 CET 2022][INFO] We will now compile your code for x86_64-microsoft-windows. This may take some time.
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:28 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Ignoring server-mode native-image argument --no-server.
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:30 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] ========================================================================================================================
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:30 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] GraalVM Native Image: Generating 'com.plpr.application.gluonapplication'...
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:30 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] ========================================================================================================================
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] [1/7] Initializing...
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]                                                                                     (4,2s @ 0,16GB)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] Error: Error parsing JNI configuration in D:\_DEV\_Eclipse_IDE\_Workspaces\PRIVATE\GluonMobile_PlaylistProfiler\target\gluonfx\x86_64-windows\gvm\jniconfig-x86_64-windows.json:
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] Field java.net.Inet6Address.cached_scope_id not found. To allow unresolvable reflection configuration, use option --allow-incomplete-classpath
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] Verify that the configuration matches the schema described in the -H:PrintFlags=+ output for option JNIConfigurationFiles.
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Error parsing JNI configuration in D:\_DEV\_Eclipse_IDE\_Workspaces\PRIVATE\GluonMobile_PlaylistProfiler\target\gluonfx\x86_64-windows\gvm\jniconfig-x86_64-windows.json:
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] Field java.net.Inet6Address.cached_scope_id not found. To allow unresolvable reflection configuration, use option --allow-incomplete-classpath
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] Verify that the configuration matches the schema described in the -H:PrintFlags=+ output for option JNIConfigurationFiles.
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:73)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.hosted.config.ConfigurationParserUtils.doParseAndRegister(ConfigurationParserUtils.java:135)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.hosted.config.ConfigurationParserUtils.lambda$parseAndRegisterConfigurations$1(ConfigurationParserUtils.java:86)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$4$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:214)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline.reduce(IntPipeline.java:515)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline.sum(IntPipeline.java:473)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.hosted.config.ConfigurationParserUtils.parseAndRegisterConfigurations(ConfigurationParserUtils.java:88)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.jni.access.JNIAccessFeature.afterRegistration(JNIAccessFeature.java:128)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$setupNativeImage$14(NativeImageGenerator.java:802)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:74)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:802)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:534)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:494)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:426)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:587)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:126)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]   at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:617)
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]                          0,1s (3,0% of total time) in 8 GCs | Peak RSS: 0,85GB | CPU load: 5,50
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] Produced artifacts:
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB]  D:\_DEV\_Eclipse_IDE\_Workspaces\PRIVATE\GluonMobile_PlaylistProfiler\target\gluonfx\x86_64-windows\gvm\Gluon Mobile - Single View Project\com.plpr.application.gluonapplication.build_artifacts.txt
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] ========================================================================================================================
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] Failed generating 'com.plpr.application.gluonapplication' after 2,3s.
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] [SUB] Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][SEVERE] Process compile failed with result: 1
Check the log files under D:\_DEV\_Eclipse_IDE\_Workspaces\PRIVATE\GluonMobile_PlaylistProfiler\target\gluonfx\x86_64-windows\gvm\log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][INFO] Logging process [compile] to file: D:\_DEV\_Eclipse_IDE\_Workspaces\PRIVATE\GluonMobile_PlaylistProfiler\target\gluonfx\log\process-compile-1644243451215.log
[lun. févr. 07 15:17:31 CET 2022][SEVERE] Compiling failed.
Check the log files under D:\_DEV\_Eclipse_IDE\_Workspaces\PRIVATE\GluonMobile_PlaylistProfiler\target\gluonfx\x86_64-windows\gvm\log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.934 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-07T15:17:31+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.8:compile (default-cli) on project gluon-mobile---single-view-project--allow-incomplete-classpath: Compiling failed -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.723 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-07T15:17:31+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.8:build (default-cli) on project gluon-mobile---single-view-project--allow-incomplete-classpath: Error, gluonfx:build failed -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: no screenshots of plain text (copy and paste the xml) please

Comment: You need to use the latest plugin (1.0.12) and the latest release of Gluon's GraalVM (22.0.0.3-Final). That should fix your issue with `java.net.Inet6Address.cached_scope_id` (which was fixed a while ago).

Comment: Hello, thank you for trying to help. The latest plugin is 2.8.2 according to [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/ide-plugins/blob/master/eclipse/CHANGELOG.md). And the version I'm using GraalVM Gluon 22.0.0.2-Final is only a few days old. But I will try tomorrow to change to 22.0.0.3 from [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/graal/releases). Thank you for pointing this out !

Comment: @kelopatra : I have enclosed links to all original files. I thought that to point out most important parts of them, and relevant for the question was better than just through the complete files. Also it points out the research I made to ease the 'helper'. I was asked to do so in another post ;-). Is it not ok if I provide both ?

Comment: @Daric 2.8.2 is the IDE plugin, and with it you have created your Maven project. The pom has some more plugins, and there you will find the GluonFX plugin which should be 1.0.12, not 1.0.8. Additionally you can upgrade the GraalVM version too.

Comment: Haaaaaa... Thank you !!!! Got it now ;-) !

Comment: Thank you @José_Pereda, the simple plugin update solved the problem exposed in question ! Should you not write the answer ? I will do it gladly, but don't want to take the credit for it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[José Pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956070/jos%c3%a9-pereda), which has an amazing 'Coding Blog' [here](http://jperedadnr.blogspot.com/), spotted that my plugin version was outdated.
He pointed out that there are 2 plugins used in the development process :

- The IDE one, in my case Eclipse, which the latest as of 2022.02.08, is 2.8.2.
- The 'POM' one, which was set by default to 1.0.8, and I had to set as 1.0.12.
  That solved the problem described in my question. Here is a screenshot of the updated POM, which can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-LrcqM1G4-PsDOTHYRvjs9xn2JoC8ixj/view?usp=sharing) :
  [image]

  Another issue I found was my custom argument `--allow-incomplete-classpath` for the native build was set incorrectly. It has to be set in the 'POM' in the plugin/configuration section as follows (same POM referenced already) :
  [image]

  These 2 modifications allowed me to have a completed build, and my 'exe' file was created !